# Can I say "I can answer your apprehensions"?

Tags: word-usage

Is it proper to say that you can answer someone's apprehensions?

Comment: You could apprehend their apprehensions

Comment: It sounds like something a non-native English speaker might say. Erik's rewording would be better. Or you could say that you could *address any misgivings they might have.*

Comment: @JLG Yes, or perhaps "assuage".

Comment: It has a poetic flavor, as in "your apprehensions confuse me, dear" from the song in *The Music Man* "Where is the sin in sincere?".

Comment: Easier: I can understand your apprehensions.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't; but I might tell them I could *allay their {worries / concerns}* or *misgivings* (as JLG suggests).